# cyclic structure error when using typescript generics with vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I was trying to use typescript generics with vue,
but in the below example ( a simple one that removes unwanted details )  when running vue-tsc i'm getting

```
The inferred type of 'generateGenericComponent' references a type with a cyclic structure which cannot be trivially serialized. A type annotation is necessary.
```

```js
export function generateGenericComponent<
  T extends {
    name: string;
  }
>(names: T[]) {
  return defineComponent({
    props: {
      name: {
        type: String as PropType<T["name"]>,
      },
    },
  });
}
```

**Constraints**
I've to use PropType because the real example is a complex type.

what is the best way to  fix this error ? how can i annotate the return type for this function ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] in the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/Q)?

Comment: i don't think typescript playground supports loading external libraries. or does it ? 

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74167364/cyclic-structure-error-when-using-typescript-generics-with-vue?noredirect=1#comment130957918_74167364) It does (from npm), although they only exist in the type system — you can't actually _run_ the code. Here's an example: https://tsplay.dev/w2z1zw

Comment: thank you. i did not know that. here is the reproduction, https://tsplay.dev/WY32bN